# What is this 2D platforming game with green and blue flower-like stems?

Tags: game-identification

What is this game? I'm hoping to find out it's name:

[image: image from the game]

Answer (score 22):

It's **[Geometry Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_Dash)**, a "rhythm-based platforming game":

[image]

That's the result of searching for your picture through [Yandex](https://yandex.ru/images/search?source=collections&cbir_id=2770798%2F5Y697csfBm0RvqrlSXSlpg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2Fwx83r.jpg&rpt=imagelike).

Answer (score 18):

It is one of the Geometry Dash games, namely:

- Geometry Dash
- Geometry Dash Meltdown
- Geometry Dash World
- Geometry Dash SubZero